# Downloading text files: Perl

Tags: perl, lwp-useragent

The files are not downloading, please help.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
require HTTP::Response;
require LWP::UserAgent;
open (INPUT, "ndb_id_file.txt") or die "can't open ndb_id_file.txt";
@input = <INPUT>
foreach $line(@input) {
    $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
    $ua->env_proxy('http');
    $ua->proxy(['http', 'ftp'],'http://144020019:*******@netmon.****.ac.in:80');
    response = 
        $ua->get('www.ndbserver.rutgers.edu/files/ftp/NDB/coordinates/na-biol/$line');
    if ($response->is_success) {
        $content = $response->content();
        open(OUT,">$line.pdb") or die "Output file $line cannot be produced... Error...";
        print (OUT "$content");
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `use warnings` and `use strict` in your code.

Comment: I used strict and warnings. It says that $response, content and line require an explicit package name. I checked whether perl modules are present by cpan LWP::UserAgent and cpan HTTP::Response through command line.It says both modules are upto date

Comment: That's funny. Even without those measures in place, I get `Unquoted string "response" may clash with future reserved word at E:\Perl\source\resp.pl line 10.`, `syntax error at E:\Perl\source\resp.pl line 6, near "$line("`, `syntax error at E:\Perl\source\resp.pl line 17, near "}"`, `Execution of E:\Perl\source\resp.pl aborted due to compilation errors.` Are you really unable to fix those problems yourself?
`

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of problems with your program. The major ones being in this line

```
response = $ua->get('www.ndbserver.rutgers.edu/files/ftp/NDB/coordinates/na-biol/$line');
```

- You are trying to assign to `response`, which is not a variable name
- the value of `$line` is not being inserted into the URL because you are using single quotes
- The contents of `$line` end with a linefeed, which should be removed using `chomp`
- The URL has no *scheme* — it should start with `http://`

Apart from those points, you should fix these issues

- You *must always* `use strict` and `use warnings` at the top of *every* Perl program you write. Adding `-w` on the shebang line is far inferior
- You should `use` rather than `require` `LWP::UserAgent`. And there is no need to also `use HTTP::Response` as it is loaded as part of LWP
- You should always use the *three-parameter* form of `open` with lexical file handles. And if the `open` fails you should print a `die` string that includes the value of `$!` which gives the *reason* for the failure
- You should use `while` to read data from a file one line at a time, unless you have a good reason to need all of it in memory at once
- There is no need to create a new user agent `$ua` every time around the loop. Just make one and use it to fetch every URL
- You should use `decoded_content` instead of `content` to fetch the content of an `HTTP::Response` message in case it is compressed

Here is a program that includes all of those fixes. I haven't been able to test it but it does compile

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use LWP::UserAgent;

my $in_file = 'ndb_id_file.txt';

open my $fh, '<', $in_file or die qq{Unable to open "$in_file" for input: $!};

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
$ua->env_proxy('http');
$ua->proxy(['http', 'ftp'], 'http://144020019:*******@netmon.****.ac.in:80');

while ( my $line = <$fh> ) {

    chomp $line;
    my $url = "http://www.ndbserver.rutgers.edu/files/ftp/NDB/coordinates/na-biol/$line";
    my $response = $ua->get($url);

    unless ( $response->is_success ) {
      warn $response->status_line;
      next;
    }

    my $content = $response->decoded_content;
    my $out_file = "$line.pdb";

    open my $out_fh, '>', $out_file or die qq{Unable to open "$out_file" for output: $!};
    print $out_fh $content;
    close $out_fh or die qq{Unable to close "$out_file": $!};
}
```